# Bokeh 12.0.15- stacked grouped bars

Tags: python, bokeh, stacked-chart

Is there a way to create stacked-grouped bar charts in the current version of bokeh?

Currently I'm attempting to create a list of tupled groupings to pass as an x-axis:

i.e.

```
from bokeh.io import show, output_file, curdoc
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, HoverTool, FactorRange
from bokeh.plotting import figure

factors = [
    ("2017","jan"),("2017","feb"),("2017","mar"),
    ("2018",'jan'),("2018","feb"),("2018","mar")
    ]
data = {'factors' : factors,
        'Tammy'   : [2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 4],
        'Jim'   : [5, 3, 4, 2, 4, 6],
        'Mike'   : [3, 2, 4, 4, 5, 3]}

users=['Tammy','Jim','Mike']

source = ColumnDataSource(data=data)

p = figure(x_range=FactorRange(*factors), plot_height=350)

p.vbar_stack(users, x=factors, width=0.9)

curdoc().add_root(p)
```

It's not working all that great currently..

`Keyword argument sequences for broadcasting must be the same length as stackers`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this works

```
from bokeh.core.properties import value
from bokeh.io import show, output_file, curdoc
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, HoverTool, FactorRange
from bokeh.plotting import figure


years = ["2015", "2016", "2017"]
colors = ["#c9d9d3", "#718dbf", "#e84d60"]

data = {'factors' : [("2017","jan"),("2017","feb"),("2018","jan")],
        'Tammy'   : [2, 1, 4],
        'Jim'   : [5, 3, 4],
        'Mike'   : [3, 2, 4]}

users=['Tammy','Jim','Mike']

source = ColumnDataSource(data=data)

p = figure(x_range=FactorRange(*factors), plot_height=350, )

p.vbar_stack(users, x='factors', width=0.9, source=source, color=colors)

p.y_range.start = 0
p.x_range.range_padding = 0.1
p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
p.axis.minor_tick_line_color = None
p.outline_line_color = None
p.legend.location = "top_left"
p.legend.orientation = "horizontal"

curdoc().add_root(p)
```

Thanks for listening to me broadcasting for the past hour.